# Concatenate strings and variable values

Tags: python, r, concatenation, string-concatenation

I would like to concatenate strings and variable values in Python 3. 
For instance, in `R` I can do the following:

```
today <- as.character(Sys.Date())
paste0("In ", substr(today,1,4), " this can be an R way")
```

Executing this code in `R` yields `[1] "In the year 2018 R is so straightforward"`.

In `Python 3.6` have tried things like:

```
today = datetime.datetime.now()
"In year " + today.year + " I should learn more Python"
```

`today.year` on its own yields `2018`, but the whole concatenation yields the error: `'int' object is not callable`

What's the best way to concatenate strings and variable values in Python3?

Comment: do you know how to use `sprintf` in R? the same can be accomplished in python by applying the % operator to a string. you can also `.format` a string.

Comment: Try `"In year " + str(today.year) + " I should learn more Python"`.

Comment: The other commenters/answerers are giving you alternative approaches, but I think your code may have another issue. Rather than an error that says `'int' object is not callable'`, I would expect a `TypeError` saying `cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects`.

Comment: @nicola This worked fine and as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try to convert today.year into a string using str().

It would be something like that:

```
"In year " + str(today.year) + " I should learn more Python"
```

Answer (score 1):

If we need to use `.` way then `str()` is equivalent to `__str__()`

```
>>> "In year " + today.year.__str__() + " I should learn more Python"
# 'In year 2018 I should learn more Python'
```